# firebase api for angularjs

Tags: angularjs, api, firebase

I am using firebase for my web and android app. Now, I am trying to call http GET function from firebase to retrieve data but it returns this error message

> "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.firebase.com' (redirected from 'https://example.firebase.com/') from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

```
 $http.get('https://example.firebase.com').then(function(response){
    $ctrl.tempData = response.data;
    console.log('response data', response.data);
 }
```

I found something called curl in somewhere else, but how to actually apply on this?

Comment: Why are you not using the Firebase JavaScript SDK that's meant for use in web applications?  That's the preferred way to access Firebase.  Or AngularFire?

Comment: At the very least you'll want to make sure the URL ends in `.json`, since you're trying to access the REST API. So `$http.get('https://example.firebase.com/.json')...`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow CORS it's [configurable on Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config) via the `firebase.json` file. However, the JavaScript SDK (web client sdk) is the way most people interact with Firebase from the browser.

> ```
> "hosting": {
>   // Add the "headers" attribute within "hosting"
>   "headers": [ {
>     // Specifies a CORS header for all font files
>     "source": "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",
>     "headers": [ {
>       "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
>       "value": "*"
>     } ]
>   }, {
>     // Overrides the default 1 hour browser cache with a 2 hour cache for all image files
>     "source": "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
>     "headers": [ {
>       "key": "Cache-Control",
>       "value": "max-age=7200"
>     } ]
>   }, {
>     // Sets the cache header for 404 pages to cache for 5 minutes
>     "source": "404.html",
>     "headers": [ {
>       "key": "Cache-Control",
>       "value": "max-age=300"
>     } ]
>   } ]
> }
> ```